# I would like to list all columns under each table in my Schema in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to get the list of tables and the list of columns under each table with the type and size display in Oracle for a specific schema

Comment: How are you trying to do this?

Comment: a flat report would be simple enough, select * from dba_tab_cols group by table...but what about a visual report, say a data model relational diagram?

Answer (score 0):

Use the system tables/views...

```
SELECT owner, table_name, Column_Name, data_Type, data_length, 
  Data_Precision, nullable 
FROM all_tab_cols where owner = 'SCHEMA_NAME'
```

For a list of system/tables views you have access to...

`Select * from Dictionary;`